# Data Annotation MVC

Tags: c#, jquery, html, asp.net-mvc

How can I add a required field ONLY if I have a value in my username model.

I have:

```
@Html.PasswordFor(
    model => model.Password, 
    new { required = "This field is required" }
)
```

I want :

```
@Html.PasswordFor(
    model => model.Password, 
    new { if (Model.UserName != null) {required = "This field is required"} }
)
```

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well instead of using an `if` statement, you can always use the ternary operator `?:`

```
@Html.PasswordFor(
    model => model.Password, 
    new { required = Model.UserName != null ? "This field is required" : null }
)
```

Alternatively (if setting `required` as null does not work) then you could use it one level up:

```
@Html.PasswordFor(
    model => model.Password, 
    Model.UserName != null
        ? new { required = "This field is required" }
        : new { }
)
```

Comment: @zakzak Cool, did the first version work in the end?

Comment: @Html.PasswordFor(model => model.Password, Model.UserName != null ? new { required = "" } : null))

Yes with the Null it works perfectly, thank you again :)

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use

```
if(Model.UserName != null) 
{
    @Html.PasswordFor(model => model.Password, new { required = "This fiels is required"})  
}
else
{
    @Html.PasswordFor(model => model.Password)
}
```

Why do you need to complicate thing?